# Get Params in Scheme Webview

Tags: webview

[image]

I want get params Id in url when user click button **Update ObjectID** in Webview.
My code:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        // Campain
        String data_campain = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
        AppLog.log(data_campain);
    }
```

But not working.